# Deleted comb space is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Consider the following proposition $13.14$:
[image]

I'm confused with the fourth line in the proof. The author says "we claim that there exist $t_1 \in (t_0,1]$ such that $(P_1 \circ \gamma)(t_0,t_1) \subseteq K$"

Why we claim this?  What is the necessity to proving this claim?  Is there anything special for this claim?

Can anybody explain it a bit more?

Still one more question: How $(P_1 \circ \gamma)(t_0)=0$ in the last line?

Added: Here's the  more detailed expansion of the deleted comb space and its figure:[image]

Here $D$ is same as $C_0$ in our proposition

Comment: Do they mean that the deleted comb space is $E\times(\{0\}\times\{1\})$? Or something else?

Comment: @Arthur No, $E \cup \{(0,1)\}$. So the comb space minus $\{0\} \times (0,1)$.

Comment: @Arthur: refer example $13.13$ for notation clarifications

Comment: Munkres in his text proves that $f^{-1}[\{p\}]$ is both closed-and-open to get a contradiction.

Comment: @LDM That is what I'm doing. I'm asking whether the definition of the deleted comb space in example 13.13 is a typo, because the way it's written doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Arthur this is another text like Munkres that writes $0 \times 1$ for the point with coordinates $(0,1)$. That should end...

Comment: @Arthur: I add a picture for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your questions in a second, but here is what's going on in the proof. If there were a continuous path from $0\times 1$ to $1\times 0$, then the path must "leave" the point $0\times 1$ at some point $t_0$. The question becomes: where does the path go right after $t_0$? Well, it can't really go anywhere, and that's the whole point.

Your first question of "why do we prove this claim"? You would know the answer to this question if you understood the rest of the proof, so I'll try explaining the rest of the proof.

Look at the set $(P_1\circ \gamma)(t_0,t_1)$. According to the claim, it is a subset of $K$. Since $(t_0,t_1)$ is a connected interval and $P_1\circ\gamma$ is a continuous function, $(P_1\circ \gamma)(t_0,t_1)$ is a *connected* subset of $K$. But then it must be a singleton. This is a huge deal. What it's telling us is that $\gamma(t)$ has the same $x$-coordinate for $t \in (t_0,t_1)$, i.e. that right after we "leave" the point $0\times 1$, we get stuck at some vertical line with $x$-coordinate some point of $K$. And this is of course a contradiction since at $t_0$, $\gamma$ is at $0\times 1$, so $\gamma$ clearly cannot be continuous. [We took $t_0$ to be the maximum of $\gamma^{-1}(\{p\})$ because this is the first time $\gamma$ "leaves" $0\times 1$].

Finally, "How is $(P_1\circ \gamma)(t_0) = 0$?".  $\gamma(t_0) = 0\times 1$ by definition of $t_0$. So, $(P_1\circ \gamma)(t_0) = 0$.

Comment: Yes! I understand what you are saying! and Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to proceed after introducing $t_0$: By continuity, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $t\in (t_0,t_0 + \delta)$ implies $|\gamma (t)-p| < 1/2.$ For such $t,$ $\gamma(t)\ne p$ and $\gamma(t)$ has second coordinate at least $1/2.$ Thus

$$\gamma((t_0,t_0 + \delta)) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{1/n\}\times [1/2,1].$$

Because $\gamma((t_0,t_0 + \delta))$ is connected, it cannot intersect more than one of the compact line segments in the union above, say $\{1/n_0\}\times [1/2,1].$ We then arrive at

$$p=\lim_{t\to t_0^+} \gamma (t) \in \{1/n_0\}\times [1/2,1],$$

contradiction.

Comment: This helps too! thanks!